# React Native StyleSheet "curry" is not a valid style property

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-elements

I'm currently developing two apps using react native, both have `react-native-elements@2.0.0` as dependency and both are using `react-native@0.62.2`.

I'm getting a strange error that only occurs on one of those apps.

```
Invariant Violation: "curry" is not a valid style property.
StyleSheet thumbHorizontal: undefined
Valid style props: [
```

I've tracked this error to `react-native-elements/Slider`, however I do not believe it's a bug as this only occur on one of the apps.

As a quick fix I deleted the following lines from `node_modules/react-native-elements/src/slider/Slider.js`

```js
  thumbHorizontal: height => ({
    top: 22 + (height ? (height - 4) / 2 : 0),
  }),
  thumbVertical: width => ({
    left: 22 + (width ? (width - 4) / 2 : 0),
  }),
```

Comment: You're trying to use a function instead of an object; try calculating the value of `top` beforehand and passing it directly.

Comment: The code that I deleted is part of the `react-native-elements`.
https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements/blob/next/src/slider/Slider.js#L620